# Get records from database and insert in specific row

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, html-table

I have a select query that retrieves all data from 2 tables using `INNER JOIN`. One of the tables is called `Rack_Monitor` and the otherone is called `Rack_Content`. Rack_Monitor has a column named `TotalUnits` ( for example 48 ). Rack_Content has a column named `Units` ( for example 3 or 3;4 the delimiter is a ; if it contains multiple units.

**Question:**

Now I need to build a table in Twig that loops 48 times (TotalUnits) and check if there is any content to fill. If not than the row must be empty.
The array will start at 0 and the content of that array has a unit of 3;4 so it has to be placed on the 3rd and 4th row of the table.

**Code looping 48 times:**

```
<table class="table" id="diagnosis_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% set TotalUnits = RackContent[0].TotalUnits %}
    {% for i in 1.. TotalUnits %}
      <tr>
        <td class="priority" style="">{{ i }}</th>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This code is showing 48 rows of numbers for the table.

**I'm stuck with the next code. This is what I've got so far. Am I on the right track?:**

```
                   <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
  <table class="table" id="diagnosis_list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Intern IP</th>
      <th>Extern IP</th>
      <th>Backup</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for i in 0..TotalUnits %}

        {% if RackContent[i] is defined %}
          {% set UnitSplit = RackContent[i].Units|split(';') %}
          <tr>
            <td><h5>HostName</h5><small>Webserver</small></td>
            <td><h5>InternIP</h5><small>WebserverInternIP</small></td>
            <td><h5>IPMI IP</h5><small>WebserverIP</small></td>
            <td><h5>BackupserverIP</h5></td>
            <td><a class='btn btn-warning'>
                <i class="fa fa-edit text-white"></i>
                </a>
              <a class='btn btn-danger'>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o text-white" onclick="Delete(2)"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% else %}
          <tr>
            <td><h5>Empty</h5><small>Empty</small></td>
            <td><h5>Empty</h5><small>Empty</small></td>
            <td><h5>Empty</h5><small>Empty</small></td>
            <td><h5>Empty</h5></td>
            <td><a class='btn btn-warning'>
                <i class="fa fa-edit text-white"></i>
              </a>
              <a class='btn btn-danger'>
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o text-white" onclick="Delete(2)"></i>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Why I've 2 tables set up is because it is a draggable table. So the numbers are static and will not be able to move. The other table with the content can be moved up and down rows.

The code is not done yet but I just want to know if you guys will program it the same way or is there a more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it. It works fine now.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Hardware</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Intern IP</th>
                        <th>Extern IP</th>
                        <th>Backup</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for i in 1..(TotalUnits) %}
                        {% set ID = i  %}
                        {% set FoundIt = 0 %}
                        {% for R in RackContent %}
                            {% for U in R.Units %}
                                {% if loop.length == 2 %}
                                    {% if U == i and loop.index == 1 %}
                                        <tr class="success">
                                            <td>{{ ID }}</td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><h5>{{ R.Name }}</h5></td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><h5>{{ R.HostName }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServer }}</small></td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><h5>{{ R.InternIP }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServerInternIP }}</small></td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><h5>{{ R.IPMIIP }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServerIP }}</small></td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><h5>{{ R.BackupServer }}</h5></td>
                                            <td rowspan="2"><div class="dropdown">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                                        Options
                                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye text-blue"></i>Open</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit text-orange"></i>Edit</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o text-red"></i>Delete</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% set FoundIt = 1 %}
                                    {% elseif U == i and loop.index == 2%}
                                        <tr class="success">
                                            <td>{{ ID }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% set FoundIt = 1 %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% elseif loop.length == 1 %}
                                    {% if U == i and loop.index == 1 %}
                                        <tr class="success">
                                            <td>{{ ID }}</td>
                                            <td><h5>{{ R.Name }}</h5></td>
                                            <td><h5>{{ R.HostName }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServer }}</small></td>
                                            <td><h5>{{ R.InternIP }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServerInternIP }}</small></td>
                                            <td><h5>{{ R.IPMIIP }}</h5><small>{{ R.WebServerIP }}</small></td>
                                            <td><h5>{{ R.BackupServer }}</h5></td>
                                            <td><div class="dropdown">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                                        Options
                                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye text-blue"></i>Open</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit text-orange"></i>Edit</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o text-red"></i>Delete</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% set FoundIt = 1 %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if FoundIt == 0 %}
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>{{ ID }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```